# I just want to know if this is right method of doing this question.

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[image]

Here I write $x\in\emptyset$ because we know that the expression *[x(x-1)]-4[x+1.5]-2[x-3.5]* has to be an integer
So I just want to know is the correct way.

Comment: Pretty nice conclusion, another way (one less step) would be to notice that even=odd in the antipenultimate line for any solutions x.

Comment: Welp, I guess I'm using "antipenultimate" daily now.

Comment: Did you look at that image before posting it? It asks about the equation above, but the above was cut off

Comment: yeah my bad my English is weak @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: sorry, but this has nothing to do with your English. You meant to post a picture of a sheet of paper, and an important part of the sheet of paper is missing from the image

Comment: no there was nothing important above I write question myself I just write "above" instead of "below" that's it important part of the paper is already posted.

Comment: Your last line ($x\in\varnothing$) is correct only if you are asked for solutions $x$ in $\mathbb Z$. In $\mathbb R$, this quadratic equation has two solutions.

Comment: ok, it was an English problem, fine. You're not supposed to post images, btw.

Comment: If you only solve it in $\mathbb Z$,  could as well soon notice that the LHS of the "equation below" ;-) is a multiple of $4$, whereas the RHS, $7+4(x-7/2)=4x-7$, is not.

Comment: yeah I didn't see that, thank you @AnneBauval

Comment: You can even replace "multiple of $4$" by "multiple of $2$".